# Remove margin/padding/space beneath label

Tags: html, css

On this picture you see a label beside a *a-link*.

[image]

CSS for both:

```
.btn {
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #666;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;

    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

How to remove the space beneath the label?

Comment: Which one is the link? And please provide a jsfiddle containing your markup and css.

Comment: Can you recreate in a fiddle or something?

Comment: That extra spacing is coming from somewhere else in your code. Inspect with dev tools maybe to find the problem, here's the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/35fL6/

Comment: Or display block, or display:inline-block them both

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the **line-height**.

```
.btn {
 line-height: 1.4em;
}
```

[image]